# Trying to generate a list using python script

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to generate a list python. In this program i am trying to write a function that takes a list value from keyboard and returns a string with all the items separated by a comma and a space, with **"and"** inserted before the last item. 
For example, passing the previous spam list to the function would return 
**'apples, bananas, tofu, and cats'**. Her is my code

```
spam=[]

def rock(val):
    while True:
        print("Enter the text: ")
        val=input()
        spam.append(val)
        return spam


print("Enter the number: ")
n=int(input())
for i in range(0,n):
    s=', '.join(rock(''))
    print(s)

Output:
Enter the number: 
3
Enter the text: 
rock
rock
Enter the text: 
dog
rock, dog
Enter the text: 
cad
rock, dog, cad
```

Now, in the above mention program i have succeed to generate a list which is separated by comma. But i can't figure out how to put **"and"** just before the last value. like this, **'apples, bananas, tofu, and cats'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just join the head of the list using ", " and then join using ", and", for example:

```
words = ["apples", "bananas", "tofu", "cats"]

head = ", ".join(words[:-1])
result = ", and ".join( [head, words[-1]] )

print(result)
```

(the last could be concatenated directly: `result = head + ", and " + words[-1])

Comment: it's giving syntax error.

Comment: @Jordan Where do you get syntax error? I've verified using both `python` and `python3`. I've updated the answer with example input data and a printout of the result.

Comment: thank you so much code is working perfectly fine.